# SQL JOINING main table with two tables returning number of records - maximum of other two tables?

Tags: sql, join, db2, left-join

I have my MAIN table T1 from which I am doing select of many fields:

```
ID
1000
```

I have table T2:

```
ID      SERVICE
1000    IPTV
1000    VOIP
```

I have table T3:

```
ID      DEVICE
1000    MODEM
1000    ROUTER
1000    DVC
```

I want to JOIN   T1  with  T2 or T3 which can but also and might not have values at all  !!!!
When they have values I want to have in SELECT number of records of maximum number of records from T2 or T3. So in this case T3 has 3 records which is maximum and I want 3 records in SELECT. (in case that T2 has 3 records that would be maximum in case that T3 has 2 records)

But in my SELECT statement I am having 5 records which I do not want. What is the correct expression for that? My below query returns 5 records (I want 3)

```
select t1.id,t2.service,t3.device
from t1
left outer join T2 on t1.id=t2.id
left outer join T3 on t1.id=t3.id
```

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want? Doesn't sound right to me

Comment: Well yes. I want result  1000  IPTV MODEM   1000 VOIP ROUTER  1000 NULL DVC

Comment: Can you specify the database and version?

Comment: No it does not!!! I have customer who wants to see for some record affected services and devices.They are not connected between them! So he does not want to see 5 records , to him it is enough to put all information in 3 records in my example. Does now sounds OK? Regards

Comment: Your query would return 6 rows, not 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.id
  , t2.service
  , t3.device
FROM
        t1
    LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY service) AS rn
                , id
                , service
              FROM
                  t2
            ) AS t2
        FULL JOIN 
            ( SELECT
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY device) AS rn
                , id
                , device
              FROM
                  t3
            ) AS t3
          ON  t3.id = t2.id
          AND t3.rn = t2.rn
      ON COALESCE(t2.id, t3.id) = t1.id ;
```

Comment: This works ypercube thanks but just small question. If first row in T2 is VOIP and from T3 DVC, and second from T2 is selected INTERNET and from T3 ROUTER after joining I would like to have result 1000 VOIP DVC, 1000 INTERNET  ROUTER. But instead because of alphabetical order my result is 1000 INTERNET DVC, 1000 VOIP ROUTER. Can this be changed somehow? what is first row in T2 and T3 to be in joining result? Great job anyway

Comment: Change the `ORDER BY service` and `ORDER BY device`, inside the `OVER(...)`, with the ordering you want.

Comment: You say *"If first row in T2 is VOIP and ..."* There is no such thing in SQL as implicit ordering of tables. Tables have no default ordering. It may appear they have but  they do not. If you have a Primary Key in the table, perhaps you can use that for ordering.

Comment: I just deleted ORDER BY and it works. Man you are pure GENIUS!!! I got two minuses for this question from two persons who does not understand purpose of  SQL and what you can get from it if customers wants it on that way! Thank you once again, you saved me. I wish I can give you more than one plus!

Comment: I suppose this type of query is best suited to be dealt by application code. You could just hit two queries, one with `FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2` and one with `FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t3` and deal with the presentation in the application.

Answer (score 0):

this requirement doesn't sound right, but the following should work

```
SELECT T1.*, z2.ID, z2.SERVICE FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, CASE WHEN SUM(INDICATOR) >=0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END AS INDICATOR FROM
    (
    SELECT ID, SERVICE, 1 AS INDICATOR FROM t2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID , DEVICE AS SERVICE , -1 AS INDICATOR FROM t3
    ) z
  GROUP BY ID
) z1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ID, SERVICE, 1 AS INDICATOR FROM t2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID , DEVICE AS SERVICE, -1 AS INDICATOR FROM t3
) z2
ON z1.ID = z2.ID AND z1.INDICATOR = z2.INDICATOR
RIGHT JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = Z2.ID
```

Comment: can you please check your query once again. My MAIN table is T1 I want from there to select some more fields which i didn't write them , but in T1 I have fields on example STATUS,DATE,OWNER etc...where in your code should I include them because you started select from T2.

Comment: does your code include cases when T2.ID or T3.ID are empty or both? T1.ID is never empty

Comment: changed the T1 inner join to a right join to take care of it.